# Using ASMX Web Reference in Windows Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-services

Is it possible to create a windows service where Web References are used?

I've written a windows service file which compiles up until I add my web references. The .vb code enclosed runs as a .aspx file in a different project, so the code is not erroneous. I, however, have been able to find no documentation claiming I cannot use a Web Reference in a windows service.

If I cannot use Web References in a windows service, how should I make a call to a .asmx from a windows service project?

Comment: In a window service you can only call WCF services, not ASMX services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible to use an ASMX web service inside a Window Service. You must use a WCF service.

Comment: Thank you, very concise answer